# What goes wrong in this "proof" that $ 2 \pi i = 0 $?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

My textbook on complex numbers showed this example:

$$ \ln(-\sqrt e) = \ln(-1) + \ln(\sqrt e) = \ln(e^{\pi i}) + \ln(e^{\frac 12}) = \tfrac 12 + \pi i $$

Now, using the same logic, I got this:

$$ \begin{aligned} \ln(5) &= \ln(-1 \cdot -1 \cdot 5) \\\\ &= \ln(-1) + \ln(-1) + \ln(5) \\\\ &= \ln(e^{\pi i}) + \ln(e^{\pi i}) + \ln(5) \\\\ &= \pi i + \pi i + \ln(5) \\\\ &= 2 \pi i + \ln(5) \end{aligned} $$

Subtract $ \ln(5) $ from both sides, and get:

$$ 2 \pi i = 0 $$

Which of course isn't true. I realise that when rotating, $ 2 \pi i $ radians is the same as $ 0 $ radians, but that doesn't explain to me why $ 2 \pi i $ would always be the same as $ 0 $.

I would like to hear by which step my 'proof' went wrong. Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Branches_of_the_complex_logarithm

Comment: I think the OP made a typing error when writing what the *textbook* gave as an example:  Of course $\ln(-\sqrt e)= \ln(-1)\color{red}+ \ln(\sqrt e)$ and not $\ln(-\sqrt e)= \ln(-1)\color{green}\cdot \ln(\sqrt e)$ as the OP typed.  But that was immediately corrected and when the OP got around to asking *their* question about *their* false proof the mistake wasn't made.  That typo is *not* the source of the problem and I'm pretty sure it is not an issue of confusion for the OP. (What *is* the issue is the concept of $\ln$ as a "branch" rather than a 1-1 function.)

Comment: tl;dr.  As $e^{w} = e^{w + 2k\pi i}$ the natural logarithm is a "multi-valued" function when applied to the complex numbers.  So when we say $\ln x = w$ we don't meant that $w$ is the one and only value where $e^w =x$.  We mean that $w$ is a *representative* of a possible natural log.  As such we don't really have a rule that $\ln (ab) = \ln a + \ln b$, so much as a rule $\ln ab \equiv \ln a + \ln b \pmod{2\pi i}$.   As $0 \equiv 2\pi i \pmod {2\pi i}$ there is no contradiction in your proof.

Comment: Which textbook and which page number?  Sometimes the context in which you find the example matters more than the literal example, but I can't tell whether that's the case without actually seeing the context.